# ExtJS: How to let user enter a value in Combobox that is not in store

Tags: events, select, extjs, combobox, listener

I have a combobox which is a list of various addresses. When any address is selected, the select event plots this address on map. I want to change this program in such way that, if a user enters an address which is not a part of the Combo store, this address should still be plotted on the map. I do not require to modify the combo store. How can this be done? What event listener can trigger such event? Do I need to swap to a textfield?

```
{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                name: 'address1',
                style: {
                    marginLeft: '15px'
                },
                store: Ext.create('MyStore'),
                valueField: 'address',
                displayField: 'address',
                triggerAction: 'all',
                emptyText: 'Select Address',
                typeAhead: true,
                minChars: 2,
                typeAheadDelay: 100,
                queryMode: 'remote',
                width: 300,
                queryParam: 'searchAddress',
                hideTrigger:true,
                listeners: {                        
                    select: function(combo, records, eOpts){
                        //Plot the address from records[0].data.address
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: How does a user indicate that they want the address plotted?

Comment: You would either have to require the user to explicitly indicate that they want the address plotted (e.g. press Enter or click something), OR your combo would need to be extra smart and considerate by checking if what user has entered is a valid address that can be plotted and plotting it once that is the case.

Comment: @Drake - "your combo would need to be extra smart and considerate by checking if what user has entered is a valid address that can be plotted and plotting it once that is the case" -- how can i do this?

Comment: That would involve making a background AJAX call to the backend app while user is typing. It would check if the address is valid in which case a "plot it" response will be sent back to the combo. Also, check [this example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#remote-combo). You can show valid addresses matching users' input in the dropdown and let them pick what they want to plot.

Comment: @Drake - currently, I don't need to worry about validity of the input. All i need is , if the value user is trying to enter in the combo, doesn't exist is the store, still send the value to the plot function. I am not sure about what kind of event can capture this action and get the text being typed by the user

Comment: @Reimus: The user can press enter key to indicate that the address is either selected or types in. Currently, the specialkey event can't always capture it because on enter rather than taking the typed in value, it selects the first value in store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The user can press enter key to indicate that the address is either
>   selected or types in. Currently, the specialkey event can't always
>   capture it because on enter rather than taking the typed in value, it
>   selects the first value in store

`specialkey` won't be captured indeed if the dropdown list is shown. This is because the event is simulated on `keydown` which the dropdown list intentionally stops as can be seen [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/source/BoundListKeyNav.html#Ext-view-BoundListKeyNav-method-onKeyEnter).

Still there are ways to react to user input:

**Method 1**

Use a custom [`onFieldMutation`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-onFieldMutation) method like this:

```
Ext.define('MyCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    onFieldMutation: function(e) {
        if (e.getKey() === e.ENTER) {
            // Call address plotting method here
        }
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

**Method 2**

Use `keyup`:

```
listeners: {
    keyup: {
        fn: function(e) {
            if (e.getKey() === e.ENTER) {
                // Call address plotting method here
            }
        },
        element: 'inputEl'
    }
}
```

See both methods in action: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/sdf

Comment: Thanks @Drake! this is what i implemented                                                   `code`                                                                                                             listeners: { 
                keyup: function(me, e, eOpts){
                    if (e.getKey() === e.ENTER) {
                      //plot address
                  }                             
                  element: 'inputEl'
              },
              select: function(combo, records, eOpts){
                //plot address
            }                    
            }

Comment: @KavitaC What   // Call address plotting method here means ?